# IOS5 Twitter sign in

Tags: ios, twitter, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prompt login alert with Twitter framework in iOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667921/prompt-login-alert-with-twitter-framework-in-ios5)

i'm developing an ios application and i want to allow users sign in with Twitter. Is it possible using the Twitter framework provided by ios5?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at [Single sign-on](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios#Single_Sign-On)?

Comment: yes but if the user has not set his account in the ios device, is it possible to show a dialog in order to sign in?