# Prompt login alert with Twitter framework in iOS5?

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter

As you all may know, since iOS5 there is a native Twitter framework which make it easy to post tweets from your app.

Is there a way to prompt an alert that forwards the user to the settings app and ask for username and password?

I know that i could solve the problem with the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];
```

But thats undocumented code..

Thanks in advance

Regards Billy
(My first post on SO)

Comment: Prompt login alert with Twitter framework in iOS6 :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946062/twitter-framework-for-ios6-how-to-login-through-settings-from-app

Comment: The code doesn't work on iOS 8.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to implement this, if you set up your Twitter integration to make a post on Twitter and iOS detects that there is no Twitter account set up it will do this automatically for you!

This is a screenshot of one of my apps running on my iPhone 4S on iOS 5.1

The removal of Preferences links is in reference to custom actions by the developer, as in linking to your own preferences menu. This does not apply because not only is Twitter a built in function of iOS 5 but the UIAlertView that pops up to notify you isn't handled by the developer, it is an automatic function of iOS.

[image]

Comment: Thank for you answer, right now i got the alert when trying to post but my client want a seperate settings menu with the ability to login to twitter. Maybe i should convince my client that the initial thought is wrong and just use the "standard" behaviour instead?

Comment: That would be best. Not only would that save you a lot of work, but it would keep the app in better functioning condition sense you would simply be accessing an existing framework. If this answered your quesion please mark as correct.

Answer (score 8):

In iOS5.1, we should use TWTweetComposeViewController to show the dialog since apple rejects apps using prefs:root=TWITTER.

But, I didn't like showing the tweet screen and keyboard 
so I figured out the way to hide them, but show the pop up screen.

**UPDATE:**
Apple approved my app using this trick.

[image]

```
    TWTweetComposeViewController *viewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

    //hide the tweet screen
    viewController.view.hidden = YES;

    //fire tweetComposeView to show "No Twitter Accounts" alert view on iOS5.1
    viewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {            
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    };
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];

    //hide the keyboard
    [viewController.view endEditing:YES];

    //this approach doesn't work since you can't jump to settings
//    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: How does your code actually send the tweet if the composition view is hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Here i found the way :

Display custom alert if no twitter account has been setup on your device settings:

```
    if (![TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {
            UIAlertView *alertViewTwitter = [[[UIAlertView alloc] 
            initWithTitle:@"No Twitter Accounts" 
            message:@"There are no Twitter accounts configured. You can add or create a Twitter account in Settings." 
            delegate:self 
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Settings"
            otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil] autorelease];

            [alertViewTwitter show];
   }


 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

          if (buttonIndex==0) {
                 TWTweetComposeViewController *ctrl = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
                 if ([ctrl respondsToSelector:@selector(alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:)]) {
                     [(id <UIAlertViewDelegate>)ctrl alertView:alertView
                             clickedButtonAtIndex:0];
                 }
                 [ctrl release];
          }
   }
```

Hope this will make sense :)

Comment: I'm not too fond of using the cancel button for your action and putting your real cancel button in the array of other button titles...  Seems like the only benefit is simplifying your clickedButtonAtIndex: method while you're breaking a very common convention.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, although it should automatically ask the user to login, if the user isn't logged in already.

As of `iOS 5.1` that feature has been removed, as seen [here](http://ifreejailbreak.com/ios-5-1-blocks-the-possibility-to-generate-shortcuts-for-ios-settings-without-jailbreak/)