# Twitter Framework for ios - how can I get the login page to appear?

Tags: ios5, frameworks, twitter, xcode4.5

I've been searching around and can't seem to find the answer. If the user isn't logged into Twitter on their device and they go into my app.. if they click on a twitter button that I provided, how can I direct them to the twitter login page?

Is their a login page provided by the Twitter Framework? Or do I need to direct the user to go to the settings page and login through there?

Any help that'll lead me in the right direction would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think no..i think its better to redirect to setting page by showing alert

Comment: yes posted a link once check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i said in comment its not possible to show twitter login screen ince go through this link here they are showing alert

[Prompt login alert with Twitter framework in iOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667921/prompt-login-alert-with-twitter-framework-in-ios5)