# Go to Facebook Settings iOS 6

Tags: ios, facebook, settings, alert, url-scheme

Currently I am working on an iOS app with Facebook integration. The Facebook account of the user is needed to log in in the application.

This is the part I have working though ACAccount e.g. of the Apple Developer tools. However when the user has no Facebook account setup I get an error (which is okay). Now when this happens I want to show an alert like this one:

[image: Facebook Alert]

I thought I could do this through the "prefs" url scheme. But these seem to have been removed since iOS 5.1 for the settings. Is there any way to reproduce this alert?

edit:

Found a way based on [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667921/prompt-login-alert-with-twitter-framework-in-ios5)

```
- (void)showFacebookAlert
{
    SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    //Hide keyboard and actual view, only interested in the alert.
    mySLComposerSheet.view.hidden = YES;
    [mySLComposerSheet.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

However the "keyboard" (at least on iOS 7) is visible for the first two rows. So you need to call this with a delay, then it works like:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showFacebookAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
```

Doesn't seem to work in the simulator though. It doesn't go to the settings when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. Since the prefs url scheme was removed in iOS5.1, there is no way that you can explicitly call the native settings app. This can be observed in many cases (not only FB-related) where you want to request permissions to access the user's data / location / etc but these have already been actively restricted by the user - at this point the best you can do is bring up an informative alert, explaining exactly where in the settings the user needs to go to allow the access you need.

Comment: Found "some way" here. added it to the message.

Comment: Made my point a bit more clear - there is no EXPLICIT way to call the settings app.