# Redirect to Settings Screen for Twitter Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter

In Twitter ,if User has Logged In in the Twitter Account in Settings Screen It will allow to post.Or Else it will display a Alert as **"No Twitter Accounts"** with 2 Options **"Settings"** and **"Cancel"**. If `Cancel` is Tapped it will close alert and reject post to twitter. And if `Settings` is Tapped it is not redirecting to Settings Screen.
Also i used

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];
```

But No Luck. As far as i checked all are saying as from iOS 5.1 it wont work.But i see some apps still redirecting to settings screen in iOS7.  Is it possible to redirect in iOS7.
Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Comment: u may find answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667921/prompt-login-alert-with-twitter-framework-in-ios5

Comment: Ok.so it is not possible to redirect to Settings screen ?

Comment: this is all implemented in iOS for you, yes the settings URL links have been removed, but the above functionality is handled in the twitter framework. Please read the docs on something before posting questions

Comment: did i said i implemented this twitter framework ? Please Understand the question first and comment or what ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below code in your login button's action:

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
{
    //yes user is logged in
    accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    // Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         // Did user allow us access?
         if (granted == YES)
         {
             // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
             NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

             // Set the cell text to the username of the twitter account
             NSString *userID = [[acct valueForKey:@"properties"] valueForKey:@"user_id"];
             TwitterIdStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:userID];
             FbIdStr = [[NSString alloc] init];
             NSLog(@"%@",userID);
             NSString *networkCheck = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"isNetWorkAvailable"];
             if ([networkCheck isEqualToString:@"NotConnected"])
             {
                 // not connected
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     // Display/dismiss your alert
                     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No network connection" message:@"You must be connected to the internet to proceed." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
                     [alert show];
                 });

             } else
             {
                 fNameStr = [[NSString alloc] init];
                 lNameStr = [[NSString alloc] init];
                 emailStr = [[NSString alloc] init];

                 [self startProgressViewAgain];
             }

         }
     }];
}
else
{
    //show tweeet login prompt to user to login
    TWTweetComposeViewController *viewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

    //hide the tweet screen
    viewController.view.hidden = YES;

    //fire tweetComposeView to show "No Twitter Accounts" alert view on iOS5.1
    viewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    };
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];

    //hide the keyboard
    [viewController.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ashu. it was helpful ,but i wanted to conform as whether redirecting a screen to Settings will work or not.

Comment: It will work but will make your application to go in background. I am using it in some of my apps successfully.

Comment: Is there an equivalent code for this for phonegap? Im currently working with this using phonegap and the app is for ios. I cant display the alert shown in the image above. Also I cant find a way on how to redirect to settings page once the button is clicked,