# How can move the iPhone settings page in my application

Tags: ios, iphone

In my app,I want to share some information in fb and twitter. In share concepts using SLComposeViewController. In my phone fb or twitter account is enable means it gives the alerts. if i click the "settings" button means the page move to **iPhone settings page and login the the account and after login completed again to automatically move to my app**. how can i achieve this help me!!

[image]

Comment: it may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996508/redirect-to-settings-screen-for-twitter-login

Comment: want to go settings page for login to fb and after login in fb its can move to app automatically..

Comment: It not possible, there is no API in the iOS SDK that will allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the below code to navigate to iPhone settings:

**NOTE: this will only work for ios 8 n above**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(alertView.tag == YOUR_ALERT_VIEW_TAG && buttonIndex == YOUR_SETTINGS_BUTTON_INDEX)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];

    }
}
```

And about going back to your app after login to fb or twitter, I guess, that wont be possible because you will be then using APPLE's control to login into the fb or twitter.

For Facebook, maybe you could try Facebook SDK to share and check login from within the app. Have a look at the following document:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share

and [THIS SAMPLE](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos)

Comment: @saravanaa about going back to your app after login to fb or twitter, I guess, that wont be possible because you will be then using APPLE's control to login into the fb or twitter and you dont have control over your app at that time.

Comment: Any other idea.. i want to do the share within the app. dont want to go out for login. with in app want to make login and share. help me

Comment: @saravanaa I have added some links that may be a help to you.

Comment: @saravanaa Checkout FBShareSample in the sample link.